# MkMapView causes Circular reference

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview

I try to use MapKit.h and get stuck in my very first lines of code.

My interface looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet MkMapView *iMap;      <---- POINT OF ERROR
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MkMapView *iMap;
@end
```

and get error `Expected qualifier-specifier-list before 'MkMapView'`.

I read several posts on circular references and that I should move the `#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>` statement to the implementation and added the `@class MkMapView` statement.

As a result the error vanished, but I now cannot link `iMap` to the `MkMapView` in the Xib file.

Am in an endless loop. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `@class`.
`MkMapView` should be `MKMapView` (uppercase `K`).

Comment: Thanks mate ... feel a bit embarassed